# How to keep the height of a containing div element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to draw three rectangles in a page. The top rectangle has to be much smaller than the other two. You can see the top rectangle has a `flex-grow: 1`  (compared with 5 for other rectangles).

However, once I put three images inside the top rectangle, it gets taller, so it becomes bigger than other rectangles.

What can I do to prevent the top rectangle from getting taller? I just want the pictures' size to be adjusted to fit in the original container size.

I'll be glad for a solution using flexbox features (because I'm trying to learn it).

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  display: flex;
}
div {
  flex-grow: 5;
  display: flex;
  border: solid;
  margin: 1em;
}
#top {
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
  <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
  <img src="http://i164.photobucket.com/albums/u8/hemi1hemi/COLOR/COL9-6.jpg">
</div>

<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/CrazySynthax/pen/ZBPXry

Answer (score 1):

Your max-height of 30% is bigger than the rectangles initial size. Try setting fixed height for it or lower the max-height to match the initial size. On the code pen I used max-height: 20%; and got the result you are looking for, however to be consistent on all displays I would just set the height to a fixed percentage. ex: height: 20%. Also there is no point of using max-height if you don't want your div's height to change.

Comment: Using max-height can be a good solution, but working with percents may be misleading. Do you have an idea without using percents?

Comment: In order to get your desired output you will have to set height an max height to the same number. At that point there is no need to have max height. Just set height: 50px;

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. I didn't mean that my code in the post include "max-height". I'm just looking for a solution without using percents.